# Javascript change text realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I would like to change a text in realtime how would i do that? (Javascript)

My HTML looks like this

```
<p class="fun-fact">This text will fade out</p>
<p class="fun-fact-2">and then this text will fade in</p>
```

So i have 10 different texts that i want the script too loop through randomly and then update the text in realtime (fade out / fade in new text) and each text should be on for something like 10-20 seconds each

My first thought would be just to make 10 p classes with the same positioning but have them faded out with opacity: 0 and then change the opacity to 1 and change the previous text to opacity 0 would that work?

```
                setTimeout(function() {
                $(".fun-fact").fadeTo("slow",0);
                }, 15000 );

                setTimeout(function() {
                $(".fun-fact-2").fadeTo("slow",1);
                }, 16000 );
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. but it would be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this in pure JavaScript. Below is example function which will pass through all elements having the class `fun-fact`. On each one of them it will put the new text passed in the `text` argument.

```
function realtime_text(text, cssClass) {
    // Setting a default value for the second arg (class)
    if(!cssClass)
        cssClass = 'fun-fact';

    // Get all elements with the given class
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName(cssClass);

    // Nothing found... nothing to do.
    if(!targets || 0 >= targets.length)
        return;

    // Set the text for all found elements
    for(i = 0; i < targets.length; i++)
        targets[i].innerHTML = text;
}

// ... 

realtime_text("Where am I?"); // This call will replace the text
realtime_text("Where are they?", "fun-fact-2"); // This call will replace the text
```

After you edit I see you use jQuery. Use then:

```
$(".fun-fact").html("New text to put goes here...");
$(".fun-fact-2").html("New text for second p goes here...");
```

Comment: So to add more "texts" i would just add more realtime_text("more text"); ?

Comment: Each time you call it with some new text it will be changed inside. Check my edited post for different class support. You the jQuery example at the bottom, better, if you are using jQuery already.

Comment: @HannesBrolinLagerstedt, see the edited post. I have used `class` which is reserved identifier in JS... while class definitions are not defined with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<p id="funFact">This text will change</p>


<script>

var texts = ["first", "second", "third", "etc" ];
var interval = 4000; // 4sec interval

(function change() {

  // select random item
  var randItem = texts[Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length)];
  var obj = $("#funFact");

  function updateText() {

    obj.html(randItem).fadeIn();
  }

  obj.fadeOut(updateText);
  setTimeout( change, interval);
})();
</script>
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dgzu2/

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of strings with the values you want, and have it pick one at random with your script.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74v7c/)

In this version, you can have as many text strings as you want, and with fades AND different text each time.

```
var values = ["This text will change", "Some random text", "Additional text to come!", "Hello World!", "Your code is successful!"];
var reload = 2000; //Time in milliseconds
var last = -1;

function updateMessage() {
    var i;

    do {
        //Get random index from values 
        i = ~~ (Math.random() * values.length); //The ~~ is a fast Math.floor().
    } while (i !== last); //Check that you always get different text
    last = i;

    $('.fun-fact').fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).text(values[i]).fadeIn();
    });
    setTimeout(updateMessage, reload);
}
updateMessage();  //Activate function for the first time
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/b3t5k/)**</kbd>

```
<div>
  <span>Text 1</span>
  <span>Text 2</span>
  <span>Text 3</span>
  <span>Text 4</span>
  <span>Text 5</span>
  <span>Text 6</span>
  <span>Text 7</span>
  <span>Text 8</span>
  <span>Text 9</span>
  <span>Text 10</span>
</div>
```

---

```
span {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
span:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

---

```
(function($) {
  setInterval(function() {
    // Get random number between span length and 0 which is the first child
    i  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * $('span').length) + 0);
    // Fadein span equal our random number and fadeout his siblings
    $('span').eq(i).fadeIn(400).siblings('span').fadeOut(400);
  }, 3000);
})(jQuery);
```